# How should I integrate with logarithmic differential?

Tags: integration, logarithms, substitution

I have a two variable function, f(x,y). I would like to integrate this function with respect to x in order for my result to be just as a function of y -- i.e **$\int$ f(x,y) dx = f(y)** . No problems here. However, I want to now transform this function into a log space, where essentially I would like to integrate over a logarithmic differential, i.e **$\int$ f(x,y) dln(x)** .

Is it a straightforward substitution, where I change **dln(x) to du** , and then every x in the function becomes **e$^{u}$** ? I believe it is not this simple, however I'm a bit rusty on my integration techniques.

Comment: Please read the [MathJax tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), then edit your question to correct the formatting.

Comment: @XanderHenderson What exactly is incorrect about my formatting? Seems clear to me. The reason I bolded certain areas was just for quick emphasis. Thank you!

Comment: The technique you're trying to use is called u-substitution.

Comment: @ryguy Read the linked article.  I think that if you actually read it, you might discover that the way in which you have formatted your mathematics is incorrect.  In particular, your mathematics has been formatted as plain text, which makes it less accessible to those that use screen readers, and hinders searchability via math-aware engines such as approach0.  It looks ugly, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try
$$\int f(x,y) \text{d}(\ln(x))=\int f(x,y) \frac{\text{d}(\ln(x))}{\text{d}x} \text{d}x=\int f(x,y) \frac{\text{d}x}{x}.$$

Comment: Thank you for your help! Is this suggesting that the expression I wish to integrate (with a logarithmic differential) is equivalent to simply integrating the original function divided by x, with respect to x? Or is there a special analytic approach to this?

Comment: Yes, that is right. Technically you are evaluating a Riemann-Stieltjes integral, where the Riemann sum is evaluated with respect to change in some function $f(x)$ rather than change in $x$. But in the case when $f$ (in your case $\ln(x)$) is a continuously differentiable function, $df$ can simply be replaced by $\frac{df}{dx} dx$ and evaluated as a normal Riemann integral.

Comment: Very interesting! Perhaps I am misinterpreting your statement: "But in the case when f (in your case ln( x ) ) is a continuously differentiable function..." , but my original function, f(x,y),  is not necessarily equal to ln(x). Just the differential is equal to dln(x) . Or are you simply referring to the differential being a function of x ( ln( x ) in this case)?

Comment: Sorry for the follow up question, but I'm curious as to if this holds for all types of functions (for the differential). For instance, does the function (in the differential) have to be differentiable everywhere? In this case it would not be since ln(x) is asymptotic as x approaches zero. Or does this hold for even asymptotic functions? Thank you!

Comment: I shouldn't have used the variable $f$, that was confusing. I just meant that the function $\mu(x)$ in the differential $d(\mu(x))$ should be continuously differentiable. I think the requirements on $f(x,y)$ are just that that the integral is well-defined.

Comment: Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Subrosar is valid.
I would add that this is called the Stieltjes integral (Riemann-Stieltjes or Lebesgue-Stieltjes depending on the way you build the integral). As soon as $g' = \mathrm{d}g$ (the derivative is taken in the sense of distributions) is a measure, one can define $∫ f\,\mathrm{d}g$. Remark that here this is not the case (at least if you are in dimension $1$, so that you need more generally
$∫ \frac{f(x)}{x}\,\mathrm{d}x$ to be well defined (so in particular, $f(0) = 0$. If $f(0)≠ 0$ but $f$ is $C^0$, then one can use distribution theory to get that $\mathrm{d}\ln(x)$ is the principal value of $1/x$ and so I would say that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(x,y)\,\mathrm{d}\ln(x) = \int \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}\,\mathrm{d} x.
$$

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot